# HtmlHelper encodes & as &amp;

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html-encode

How do I stop the & in the following string from being encoded as & amp;

```
public static class GoogleMaps
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayMap(this HtmlHelper html,
                        GoogleMapData mapData, int width, int height)
    {
        const string GOOGLE_MAP_API = "xxx";
        const string GOOGLE_MAP_DOMAIN = "www.google.com/maps";
        const string GOOGLE_MAP_ACTION = "/embed/v1/view";

        var tag = new TagBuilder("iframe");
        tag.MergeAttribute("width", width.ToString());
        tag.MergeAttribute("height", height.ToString());
        tag.MergeAttribute("style", "border:0");
        tag.MergeAttribute("frameborder", "0");

        string googleMapUrl = String.Format(
                                @"{0}://{1}{2}?key={3}&center={4}",
                                "https",
                                GOOGLE_MAP_DOMAIN,
                                GOOGLE_MAP_ACTION,
                                GOOGLE_MAP_API,
                                mapData.Coordinates.ToString()
                                            );
        tag.MergeAttribute("src", googleMapUrl);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());

    }
}
```

This generates an Iframe with an SRC such as this:

```
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=myAPIkey&amp;center=52.377736, 4.915779"
```

GoogleMaps ignores center (GPS coordinates)

What I want is this:

```
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=myAPIkey&center=52.377736, 4.915779"
```

Comment: Elaborate, please. Which HtmlHelper? Build-in, your own? Show more code. Currently no MVC code is involved. Just String.Format(), it doesn't HTML-encode.

Comment: the &amp; symbol is the HTML encoded format of '&'. If you don't want it to be encoded, you will need to replace the encoder with something else, your own OR you can replace &amp; by & manually using the `String.Replace()` method.

Comment: looks like its an @ at the moment

Comment: You could just return a string not an MvcHtmlString

Comment: @ corrected to & (apologies for sleepy-headed edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HtmlHelper is *supposed* to encode the ampersand.  In fact, the ampersand when used in an attribute is supposed to be encoded to be valid HTML.  The W3C validator will tell you the same thing.

Your code will work just fine, the browser will understand it, and so will the server.

Don't believe me?  See these links:

(specifically "A link in HTML (or any HTML attribute value")
http://mrcoles.com/blog/how-use-amersands-html-encode/

http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tag.Tostring()) to generate the Html tag string and then use this string in MvcHtmlString.Create() routine.